# Equivalent of IDL's then begin statement in python

Tags: python, loops, idl-programming-language

Just wondering, I have a for loop in IDL I am looking to convert. I have in IDL:

```
if ... then begin
```

I'm thinking this is just equivalent to

```
if ...:
```

In python, with the colon being then "then begin" command...

Just looking for confirmation on this, if I am correct.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right.  Is that enough confirmation?

Comment: Excellent. I was a little unsure as to exactly how that converted. (I'm new to python).